# Design a sequence detector to detect 1001 or 11

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, circuit-design, sequence-detector

I want to draw a state diagram about the sequence detector circuit. The circuit will generate a logic “1” output is a sequence of 11 or 1001 is received. I have my answer, but I don't know my answer whether correct. Please help me check.

[image]

New result here:
[image]

Comment: Looks right....

Comment: This would fail to detect the "1001" subsequence of "11001".

Comment: How can I change it?

Comment: how about my new state diagram? Is that correct?

Comment: Do you need to write this as a state machine? Because you describe a 4 bit shift register with 2 comparators.

Comment: No. I will make a state table according the state diagram and then simplify the flip flop input. Finally, I need to draw a circuit. However, I can't determine the state diagram is right or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second state machine is correct.

[image: 10&1001 State Machine]

Comment: Hi @stainlesssteelrat may i know the tool you used to draw the FSM

Comment: I believe it is DIA.